# How to enable and download IIS logs on Windows Azure?

Tags: iis, azure, azure-storage, azure-diagnostics, iis-logs

Is there a way to easily enable and download Windows Azure IIS logs for a ASP web site? I found a few articles (about transferring logs to storage) but those all seem too complicated for something that should be readily available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read this part of the Azure documentation on [How to: Configure diagnostics and download logs for a web site](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/how-to-monitor-websites/#howtoconfigdiagnostics). Basically:

- Configure Logging in Diagnostics section of Configure management page
- Download log files for your web site via FTP (see website Dashboard management page and make note of the FTP site)
- Reading log files using one of several methods described